# Node/express file download slow over local network

Tags: node.js, express, file-transfer

**Setup**

I have two computers, A and B. I have an express server running on A. A and B are both connected to the same network. B, using a web browser, connects to A and downloads a file.

**Issue**

Because these two computers are on the same network, shouldn't the file transfer speed only be limited by whatever the router can handle? When I download the file using the browser from computer A (the one that is running the server), I get roughly gigabit speeds. If I try downloading from computer B (which again, connects to A through the browser), I get anywhere from a quarter to a tenth of the speed.

**Attempts to find the problem**

- Slow router speed: I tried using a wifi transfer app installed on both computers. It transferred at roughly gigabit speeds.
- Node/Express or computer performance limitation: Computer A shouldn't be able to download the file at gigabit speeds then, right?

**Relevant code**

Not much to see here, it just streams the file

```
const filePath = uploadDirectory + '/' + file
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
stream.pipe(res)
```

As a side note, I tried testing this with two computers that are connected to the network through Ethernet. In this case, computer B was reaching 100MB/s. In my original test, computer B is a laptop connected through wifi reaching 30MB/s. However, said laptop has 802.11ac and had high speeds with the wifi file transfer app mentioned earlier, so I'm not sure if wifi is the issue..

Apologies in advance if this isn't the most appropriate place to post such a question.

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: Updated, although the code is a simple stream. I did add more information that came from more tests below it.

Comment: are the speeds the same if you just use the express static router?

Comment: @DennisSubachev Have you found the reason/solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.